# Remove first three occurrences of space

Tags: regex, sed

I need to remove the first three occurrences of space per line in a text file.

I have tried the following:

```
sed 's/ //3'
```

This only removes the third occurrence.

```
sed 's/ //3g'
```

This leaves the first three occurrences of space alone and removes all of the following, this is the exactly the opposite of what i want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sed -e 's/ //' -e 's/ //' -e 's/ //'
```

Comment: `'s/ //;s/ //;s/ //'` I saved 10 chars!

Comment: I can't believe that i did not think about this solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/ \([^ ]*\) \([^ ]*\) /\1\2/' < filename
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed 's/ \{1,3\}//' < file.txt`

Comment: Only gets the first one for me... you sure?

Comment: Oooooooh.  Actually, 3 consecutive spaces was what I thought he was after, but yeah.